# Pylance import speech recognition could not be resolved

Tags: python, module, pylance

I've got some issue with python. I want to import Speech Recognition module and though it's installed already pylance couldn't resolve it[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UEE9.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Reload Window. If the error still exists, check if you install the module in your selected interpreter environment.